# Turtle Mini-Project - Udacity - Python - Drawing / moving a shape around another shape

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a flower, where yellow lines are drawn out from its approximate center, for the entire circumference.

The issue I have is getting a line to draw out, go to center, and draw out again the same length, but be 10 degrees greater than the previous one.

I can't wrap my mind around how to do this, the line just either bounces back and forth repeatedly, OR it pivots around the side (such as when I make a pointed shape).

So how do I get this yellow line to call back, and incrementally feather out / get that pointed shape to continually draw itself the full 360 degrees?

This is my first 'real' program I guess. I have no prior programing experience, and have only started doing this for a few days. The code I used in the function "draw_feather()" is from another site, because I didn't know how to pivot a triangle in a circle.

```
import turtle

def draw_fractal(ink):
    for i in range(1,37):
        ink.circle(50)
        ink.right(10)


def draw_feather(ink):
    while True:
        ink.forward(200)
        ink.left(170)
        if abs(ink.pos()) < 1:
            break

def draw_stem(ink):
    ink.goto(1,-400)
    ink.home()
    ink.goto(5,-400)
    ink.home()
    ink.goto(3,-400)

def Draw():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor =("White")

    R = turtle.Turtle()
    R.shape("circle")
    R.color("Red")
    R.setpos(4,3)
    R.speed(100)

    G = turtle.Turtle()
    G.shape("circle")
    G.color("Green")
    G.setpos(3,3)
    G.speed(100)

    B = turtle.Turtle()
    B.shape("circle")
    B.color("Blue")
    B.setpos(2,3)
    B.speed(100)

    Stem = turtle.Turtle()
    Stem.shape("circle")
    Stem.speed(100)

    Feather = turtle.Turtle()
    Feather.shape("circle")
    Feather.speed(100)
    Feather.color("Yellow")

    draw_fractal(R)
    draw_fractal(G)
    draw_fractal(B)
    draw_feather(Feather)
    draw_stem(Stem)

    window.exitonclick()

Draw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a rework of your code to literally do what you described:

```
import turtle

def draw_flower(ink):
    ink.up()
    ink.home()
    for degrees in range(10, 370, 10):
        ink.down()
        ink.forward(200)
        ink.up()
        ink.home()  # resets angle to 0 degrees
        ink.left(degrees)  # so absolute angle, not relative

def draw_stem(ink):
    ink.goto(1, -400)
    ink.home()
    ink.goto(5, -400)
    ink.home()
    ink.goto(3, -400)

def Draw():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("white")

    stem = turtle.Turtle()
    stem.color("green")
    stem.speed("fast")

    draw_stem(stem)

    flower = turtle.Turtle()
    flower.color("yellow")
    flower.speed("fastest")

    draw_flower(flower)

Draw()

turtle.done()
```

Simply go to the center of the screen, draw a yellow line, reset to the center of the screen, turn slightly and repeat.  Note that the `turtle.home()` method affects the angle of the turtle so we have to adjust for that:

[image]

Also, 100 doesn't mean anything to `turtle.speed()` beyond that it's greater than 10 -- use the symbolic arguments to make clear your intention.

Comment: Thanks. I had figured out a way to do what I wanted.
It's nice to see the same results, but in a different way. I ended up thinking about it like a graph, and knew it had quadrants, so I just called it back to a new quadrant each time.

`def draw_feather(ink):
 for i in range(1,73):
  x = -4
  y = -4
  ink.goto(x,y)
  ink.forward(150)
  ink.left(5)
  x = x + 1
  y = y + 1
 ink.home()`

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to separate it and make it format properly, and of course my 5 minute edit window closed!